# Are there any Eye-Fi compatible apps that will show histograms?

Tags: wireless, apps, eye-fi, android-app

Certain older cameras like the Canon EOS 1Ds mark II does still deliver good quality but the LCD screen on the back of the camera is really bad compared to more recent ones. It's also so small that I almost can't use it. I use an Eye-Fi card and a tablet to evaluate the images when I can't shoot tethered, but I miss the information the histogram provides. The official Eye-Fi app doesn't seem to have that feature unfortunately.

There seem to be an app called ShutterSnitch for iOS that can display histograms. However the app is not available for android. Is there an android app (that imports the images automatically on capture) that displays a histogram of the current picture?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because aside from being a shopping-type question, Eye-Fi was sold to Ricoh, rebranded as Keenai, which is now [defunct and discontinued with no explanation](https://help.keenai.com/hc/en-us/sections/360001724971-Notice-of-Keenai-Termination).

Answer (score 1):

Try Lightroom.

Basically configure your Eye-Fi to transfer photos to a given folder, then configure Lightroom to watch that folder and automatically import new images.

I haven't tried with an Android, but this is the basic setup for a laptop.